# PHP Google Geocode with curl refusing to work

Tags: php, google-maps, curl, google-api, geocoding

I'm currently trying to get the lat and lng parameters for an address through the use of the Google Geocode API in a PHP page.

I currently have the following code, but somehow it does not work through php while copying the generated address into Google Chrome does seem to work.

Can anybody see the error in the code below?

Thanks in advance!

Tom

====================================================

**The returned error is:**

```
( [error_message] => The 'sensor' parameter specified in the request must be set to either 'true' or 'false'. [results] => Array ( ) [status] => REQUEST_DENIED ) An error has occured: 1
```

**Old code with obsolete parts:**

```
$googleQuery = $_POST['txtAdres'] . ',+' . $_POST['txtPostcode'] . '+' . $_POST['txtStad'] . ',+' . $_POST['txtLand'];
$googleQuery = str_replace(' ', '+', $googleQuery);

// retrieve the latitude & longitude from the address
$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . urlencode($googleQuery) . '&sensor=false';
$url = htmlspecialchars($url);

echo $url;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
if ($response['status'] != 'OK') {
  echo 'An error has occured: ' . print_r($response);
} else {
    $geometry = $response['results'][0]['geometry'];
    $longitude = $geometry['location']['lat'];
    $latitude = $geometry['location']['lng'];
}
```

====================================================

**EDIT 1 - Added HTML code to each webpage to make it work**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

**EDIT 1 - Fixed and working code:**

```
// create address string
$googleQuery = $_POST['txtAdres'] . ', ' . $_POST['txtPostcode'] . ' ' . $_POST['txtStad'] . ', ' . $_POST['txtLand'];

// retrieve the latitude & longitude from the address
$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . urlencode($googleQuery) . '&sensor=false';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
if ($response['status'] != 'OK') {
  echo 'An error has occured: ' . print_r($response);
} else {
    $geometry = $response['results'][0]['geometry'];
    $longitude = $geometry['location']['lat'];
    $latitude = $geometry['location']['lng'];
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have invalid `$url`. Don't do `$url = htmlspecialchars($url);` before calling CURL.

Change:

```php
// ...
$url = htmlspecialchars($url);
echo $url;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// ...
```

to (or smth):

```php
// ...
echo htmlspecialchars($url);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// ...
```

#### Edit 1:

And your address generating is invalid. Instead of:

```
$googleQuery = $_POST['txtAdres'] . ',+' . $_POST['txtPostcode'] . '+' . $_POST['txtStad'] . ',+' . $_POST['txtLand'];
$googleQuery = str_replace(' ', '+', $googleQuery);
```

do:

```
$googleQuery = $_POST['txtAdres'] . ', ' . $_POST['txtPostcode'] . ' ' . $_POST['txtStad'] . ', ' . $_POST['txtLand'];
```

#### Edit 2:

Here is valid example:

```
$googleQuery = 'Sint Elooisstraat 30, 8800 Roeselare, België';
$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . urlencode($googleQuery) . '&sensor=false';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
print_r($response);
```

Comment: Removing the htmlspecialchars made it even worse. Now the error message is {
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
}

Comment: Can you show output for varible `$url`? p.s. I just tested this script and it works for me.

Comment: returned url with test data (without the htmlspecialchars): http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Sint%2BElooisstraat%2B30%2C%2B8800%2BRoeselare%2C%2BBelgi%EB&sensor=false 

The error message is:  Array ( [results] => Array ( ) [status] => INVALID_REQUEST ) An error has occured: 1

The url with htmlspecialchars: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Sint-Elooisstraat+30,+8800+Roeselare,+Belgi%C3%AB&sensor=false

Comment: Your address is invalid. [Try this](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Sint+Elooisstraat+30%2C+8800+Roeselare%2C+Belgium&sensor=false). Delete that `str_replace()` that replaces spaces to `+` and those `+` from concating post data into string; this is all done by `urlecnode()` function.

Comment: The output url is now: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Sint+Elooisstraat+30%2C+8800+Roeselare%2C+Belgi%EB&sensor=false   and the error message is still: Array ( [results] => Array ( ) [status] => INVALID_REQUEST ) An error has occured: 1

Comment: var_dump => string(44) "Sint Elooisstraat 30, 8800 Roeselare, België"

Comment: Yes I did, that works with the hardcoded address, but my form is for a customer website. So it has to parse $_POST variables and somehow that way gives another result.

Comment: Then you have encoding problems. Your HTML probably isn't in utf-8? You can convert it via `iconv`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that encoding prolem! I added the "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />" to the different pages and the problem has been solved!

Answer (score 0):

have had this issue within a CLI script.

i had to ensure that my data (which was imported from a CSV file) was UTF-8 encoded:

```
$address = utf8_encode($address);
$address = rawurlencode($address);
```

also, a string i had to pass from within the script i had to convert to ASCII first before converting it to UTF-8 (or htmlentities, which also works):

```
mb_convert_encoding('Österreich', 'US-ASCII', 'UTF-8')
```

or

```
htmlentities('Österreich', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')
```